# Issue with my powershell syntax to do an clean up

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using below PowerShell code to delete the logs in database server path

```
powershell.exe -command & {
    get-childitem -path "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\))"  -filter *_*_*_*.txt |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | remove-item -verbose
}
```

Its erroring out as in below

```
At line:1 char:25
+ powershell.exe -command & {get-childitem -path "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(D:\Microsoft SQL ...
+                         ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

I am new to PowerShell and thought adding `""` to `"&"` would suffice but its erroring again

```
powershell.exe : ScriptBlock should only be specified as a value of the Command parameter.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell.exe -command "&" {get-childitem -path "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(D:\Microsoft S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncorrectValueForCommandParameter
```

Added `""` to the path but it doesn't help

```
powershell.exe -command & {get-childitem -path "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE("D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\"))"  -filter *_*_*_*.txt | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | remove-item -verbose}
```

I need to call it from an SQL agent job under operating system command exec

Can any one help me with the syntax

Regards and Wishes
Eben

Comment: You need to wrap _the whole expression_ in quotes: `powershell -command "& { ... }"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing commands to the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-Command` / `-c` parameter:

- **If you're calling from *outside* PowerShell, omit `& { ... }` altogether, just specify `...`** - `& { ... }` is never needed and only creates overhead.

  - Additionally, if you're calling from `cmd.exe` (you're not), it's safest to *double-quote* `...` (`"..."`), and to escape *embedded* double quotes as `\"` (sic).
- **From *inside* PowerShell, omit `&`** (you do need `{ ... }` to robustly pass the commands, but this approach only works when calling from inside PowerShell):

  - Your error message suggest that `powershell.exe` was indeed called from a PowerShell session.
  - However, the question is *why* you're calling *another* PowerShell instance - as a child process - given that you're already *in* a PowerShell session - you could just execute the statements inside `{ ... }` *directly*.

---

Given your symptom, I'm wondering whether the `exec` command in your case actually already uses *PowerShell* rather than `cmd.exe` as the shell, in which case passing just the text *inside* `{ ... }` from your question would be sufficient.